# 422 Unprocessable Entity Error when sending image from Angular Frontend to FastAPI Python Backend

Tags: python, angular, angularjs, typescript, fastapi

I have an angular frontend and an python fastAPI backend.

In the **Angular frontend** i send an image like this:

```
uploadImage(image: any) {
  let formData = new FormData()
  formData.append("image",image);
  return this.http.post<any>(`${this.backendUrl}/upload`, formData);
}
```

In the **FastAPI Python backend** i receive it like this:

```
@app.post("/upload/")
async def read_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    file_contents = await file.read()
    with open("test_img.jpg","wb") as f:
        f.write(file_contents)

    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

When i run the code i get a `422 Unprocessable Entity`.

Why doesnt this work?

Comment: Have not used if before, but maybe the name mismatch between `formData.append("image",image);` and `async def read_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):`. Edit: try renaming either the form data entry `"image"` or the param `file: UploadFile` to match.